# How to resolve default gateway is not available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am using Windows 10, I am trying to connect to my phone's WiFi hotspot through the WiFi adapter I have installed in my machine.

I am seeing the connection status as limited and when I diagnosed the problem the system gave error `default gateway is not available`.

I tried uninstalling the Ethernet driver, tried with manually entering the IP configurations, I tried every possible thing I could, but I was not able to get it working. Did anybody have the same issue?

how can i resolve this?

Comment: What is your phone? If it's using Android see [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/170302/the-htg-guide-to-tethering-your-android-phone/).

Comment: personally I would start from the basics... ensure your hotspot is turned on on yoru phone. On Windows go to your wireless card configruation and change the IPv4 properties to automatically obtain IP and DNS. Attempt to connect to your hotspot. I would also test to see if turning off any firewall allows the connection to succeed. You may have an over zealous firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Does our mobile phone access the Internet through data traffic or via wireless network?

If our mobile phone is connected to the Internet through data traffic, we cannot create a mobile hotspot to share with other devices.

If our mobile phone is connected to the Internet via data traffic, we can try the following ways to troubleshoot or resolve the issue:

1. There will be an IP address after the mobile phone creates a mobile hotspot, it is the default gateway.
2. Connect the machine to the mobile hotspot of the mobile phone, the default gateway can assign IP address to machine automatically.
3. Can machine ping the default gateway?

If so, it may be that there is a problem with the mobile phone sharing mobile hotspot. We try to recreate the mobile hotspot on the mobile phone.

If not, we disconnected the computer from the mobile hotspot shared by the phone and tried to reconnect.